# Return the largest array from a set of arrays

Tags: arrays, ruby, enumerable

In Ruby what's the most elegant way to write a method that accepts a group of arrays as arguments and returns the array with the most number of elements?

```
def largest_array(*arrays)
end
```

For example, given:

```
a1 = [*0..9]
a2 = [*0..99]
a3 = [*0..49]
a4 = [*0..19]
```

`largest_array(a1, a2, a3, a4)` should return `a2`.

Note that the method must return a reference to the largest array itself, not the size. Also, in this case it doesn't matter which array is returned if there are arrays with identical sizes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using [`Enumerable#max_by`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html#method-i-max_by):

```
def largest_array(*arrays)
  arrays.max_by &:size
end


a1 = [*0..9]
a2 = [*0..99]
a3 = [*0..49]
a4 = [*0..19]
largest_array(a1, a2, a3, a4) == a2  # => true
```